# Writing angular end to end test with QUnit? (Not using angular mocks)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, qunit

Is there a way we can use QUnit to do E2E testing on Angular client?
I don't wish to mock the data from server but need to test real time response from service validating client services too.

Is there a work around, since what I've read that "angular-mock" has to be used for sending a request but it only mocks the server rather than sending an actual request to server.

I need to only code tests for service layer, therefore I'd like to make use of my QUnit tests (already written).

My last resort will be opting for Jasmine if this fails. :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a wording confusion here. The question should be "how to write integration test with AngularJS".

What you are trying to do is to test two pieces of software together, which mean no unit test, but you are also not testing the whole angularJS app, so you are not doing e2e test either.

There is a [karma-qunit-adapter](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-qunit) that suggest your service layer could be test with QUnit, but as the name of the framework suggest it is to be used for unit testing purpose, so the solution you will achieve may be hacky. You will have to write your own generic adapters to test input/output requests.